# Why can't 'ь' appear at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: граматика

I have learned the soft sign 'ь' cannot appear at the beginning of a sentence.

Would someone care to explain further?

Comment: How can I improve this question, since I do not wish to keep it if it is rated negatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[“Ь” (soft sign)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign) can be used only right after a consonant, because its purpose is to make the (preceding) consonant [to sound “softer” (i. e. palatalized)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)).